# Como chamar o programa sendEmail do Linux de dentro do Oracle

Tags: linux, oracle

Sei que o **Oracle** tem uma *package* para isto (**UTL_SMTP**), porém gostaria de usar o programa do **Linux** *sendMail*.

Alguém tem algum exemplo de código ou sabe aonde fica a documentação do **Oracle** sobre isto ?

Answer (score 1):

Existe uma documentação não oficial [nesta página](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/email-from-oracle-plsql.php):

E faço questão de colocar o exemplo que eles fornecem aqui por acreditar ser um ótimo exemplo:

A maneira mais fácil de enviar um e-mail é através do seguinte procedimento:

```sql
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE send_mail (p_to        IN VARCHAR2,
                                           p_from      IN VARCHAR2,
                                           p_message   IN VARCHAR2,
                                           p_smtp_host IN VARCHAR2,
                                           p_smtp_port IN NUMBER DEFAULT 25)
    AS
      l_mail_conn   UTL_SMTP.connection;
    BEGIN
      l_mail_conn := UTL_SMTP.open_connection(p_smtp_host, p_smtp_port);
      UTL_SMTP.helo(l_mail_conn, p_smtp_host);
      UTL_SMTP.mail(l_mail_conn, p_from);
      UTL_SMTP.rcpt(l_mail_conn, p_to);
      UTL_SMTP.data(l_mail_conn, p_message || UTL_TCP.crlf || UTL_TCP.crlf);
      UTL_SMTP.quit(l_mail_conn);
    END;
    /
```

O código abaixo mostra como chamar tal procedimento.

```sql
    BEGIN
      send_mail(p_to        => 'test@example.com',
                p_from      => 'kyllopardiun@nsa.com',
                p_message   => 'Isso é apenas um Olá Mundo.',
                p_smtp_host => 'smtp.nsa.com');
    END;
    /
```

EDITADO:

A única forma de chamar programas / processos externos é pelo pacote:

[dbms_scheduler](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/d_sched.htm), cuja documentação encontra-se especificada neste link.

Comment: grato pela atenção, por UTL_SMTP sei que é possível, mas gostaria de usar uma chamada via LINUX.

Comment: Ok, vou dar uma lida na documentação.

Comment: Usar o simples (UTL_SMTP) me parace ser a melhor solução que o comando em LINUX.

Comment: @Motta, é possível mas não é viável. Dependendo da versão sugiro que olhe também se o `UTL_MAIL` está disponível.